# Converting array to XML using values with numbers as key

Tags: php, xml

I've got an array that is constructed as follows:

```
$data = array('Artists' => array(
    array(...artist data...),
    array(...artist data...)
);
```

Unfortunatey, when using XmlWriter to convert this array to XML, I'm given an block of XML that looks like this:

```
<root>
    <Artists>
        <artist>
        ...
        </artist>
    </Artists>
    <artist>
    ...
    </artist>
</root>
```

The problem is that XmlWriter::StartElement() will not accept an integer value for a key, so the remaining items in that part of the array are shifted back under the root element, producing a malformed document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleXML` works great for your use.

Comment: Could you possibly explain how I could achieve this?